# Initializing an array of structs in C then dereference later

Tags: c, arrays, struct, function-pointers, dereference

I'm trying to build a serial command interpreter, so I want to store my commands in an array. I want each command to have a name and a function pointer so that I can compare the command name to what I typed into and then call the function. I'm not that good with C, so please help! Here is what I have so far.

The command array will be an array of structs. Each struct will have a string and a function pointer. There are errors here, but I don't know how to fix them. These are done before main.

```
typedef struct cmdStruct {
    char cmd[16];
    void (*cmdFuncPtr)(void);
}CmdStruct;

void (*ledFuncPtr)(void);
void (*cmd2FuncPtr)(void);

// assign pointers to functions
ledFuncPtr = &LedFunction;
cmd2FuncPtr = &Cmd2Function;

//build array of structs
CmdStruct cmdStructArray[] = cmdStructArray = { {"led",   ledFuncPtr   },
                                                {"cmd2",  cmd2FuncPtr  },  };
```

Later on, I will go through the struct array to compare it to the received command.

```
// go through the struct array to do string comparison on each struct's string member
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cmdStructArray); i++) {
    // string comparison of received command and string of struct
    if(strcmp(cmdStructArray[i].cmd, receivedCmd)==0) {
        // dereference function pointer
        (*cmdStructArray[i].cmdFuncPtr)(void);
    }
}
```

What parts am I doing wrong, and how do I fix them?

Comment: You are iterating i until sizeof(CmdStructArray) ie 16*sizeof(char) + size of a pointer(in your machine). which is definitely larger than in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has already been noted, your cycle makes wrong number of iterations. `sizeof array` does give you the number of elements in the array, but rather the number of bytes in the array. You have to calculate `sizeof array / sizeof *array` to get the number of elements.

Also, your function call syntax is invalid

```
 (*cmdStructArray[i].cmdFuncPtr)(void);
```

The above will not compile. You cannot specify `void` as an argument in function call. `(void)` syntax can only be used in function declarations. If the function accepts no parameters, the call should look as

```
 (*cmdStructArray[i].cmdFuncPtr)();
```

Also, this will not compile as well

```
CmdStruct cmdStructArray[] = cmdStructArray = { {"led",   ledFuncPtr   },
                                                {"cmd2",  cmd2FuncPtr  },  };
```

Why are you mentioning `cmdStructArray` in this declaration twice?

---

Some additional, essentially cosmetic remarks:

Firstly, since your commands are probably going to be string literals known at compile time, you can declare the first member of your struct as a `const char *` pointer instead of char array

```
typedef struct cmdStruct {
  const char *cmd;
  void (*cmdFuncPtr)(void);
} CmdStruct;
```

The initialization syntax does not change. This will relieve you of the need to worry about the size of the array (`16` that you currently have there).

Secondly, it is not clear why you had to declare intermediate pointers to functions `ledFuncPtr` and `cmd2FuncPtr` instead of initializing your array directly. What was the purpose of this

```
void (*ledFuncPtr)(void);
void (*cmd2FuncPtr)(void);

// assign pointers to functions
ledFuncPtr = &LedFunction;
cmd2FuncPtr = &Cmd2Function;

CmdStruct cmdStructArray[] = { {"led",   ledFuncPtr  },
                               {"cmd2",  cmd2FuncPtr }, };
```

when you could simply do this

```
CmdStruct cmdStructArray[] = { {"led",   &LedFunction  },
                               {"cmd2",  &Cmd2Function }, };
```

(without introducing `ledFuncPtr` and `cmd2FuncPtr` at all)?

Thirdly, you don't have to use `*` and `&` operators with function pointers. This will work too

```
CmdStruct cmdStructArray[] = { {"led",   LedFunction   },
                               {"cmd2",  Cmd2Function  }, };
```

and

```
cmdStructArray[i].cmdFuncPtr();
```

Anyway, this is a purely cosmetic issue, a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I'd like to add that `CmdStruct cmdStructArray[] = cmdStructArray = { {"led",   LedFunction   },
                                                {"cmd2",  Cmd2Function  }, };` i.e. double assignment is not legal in C. I'm also not sure what the original purpose of this double assignment is.

Comment: @user1294203: Yes, I missed this detail. Added to the answer. Thanks. In the OP's code the first `=` will probably be interpreted as initialization, while the second `=` - as assignment. However, the syntax of the right-hand side is invalid for assignment, not even mentioning that arrays are not assignable.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(cmdStructArray)` is not in elements, but rather in bytes.

Use `sizeof(cmdStructArray)/sizeof(cmdStructArray[0])`.